# How do I get all classes a type belongs to in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In my beginner's book to Haskell I'm going through classes and can see that some types seem to belong to multiple classes. For instance Bool is a member of Eq and Show.

If I type ":t False" I can see the *type* of False (which is Bool), but how do I view the classes that Bool is a member of?

Comment: Try `:i Bool`, short for `:info Bool`.

Comment: Note that GHCi will only tell you about classes that are currently in scope, so for example you'll have to import `Data.Bits` to see that `Bool` is in the `Bits` and `FiniteBits` classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See which Typeclasses the Type is an instance of in ghci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335694/see-which-typeclasses-the-type-is-an-instance-of-in-ghci)

Comment: Yes thank you, surprised I didn't find that answer!

Comment: Why would people vote this down?